# Sort of 'Scalar product' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have those two temp tables, and am trying to construct a select returning the following result:

```
1 W  A
1 X  -
2 Y  B
2 -  C
3 Z  D
3 Z2 E
3 -  F
```

Here is the definition of my temp tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (a INT, b VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #T2 (a INT, b VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #T1 (a, b)
VALUES (1, 'W'), (1, 'X'), (2, 'Y'), (3, 'Z'), (3, 'Z2')

INSERT INTO #T2 (a, b)
VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'D'), (3, 'E'), (3, 'F')

SELECT * FROM #T1
SELECT * FROM #T2

DROP TABLE #T1
DROP TABLE #T2
```

I have no idea which kind of join I could use ! Tried several ones but couldn't get the expected result!

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is `Y` present twice in the result ?

Comment: should repeated values show as `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.a, t2.a),
       ISNULL(t1.b,'-'),
       ISNULL(t2.b,'-')
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY a ORDER BY b) AS rn,*
        FROM   #T1) t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY a ORDER BY b) AS rn,*
                        FROM   #T2) t2
                    ON t1.a = t2.a
                       AND t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: @lad2025 - Yep.. didn't check it well

Comment: I guess you wanted `ISNULL` instead of `NULLIF` :)

Comment: @lad2025 - I should sleep I think :\

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OUTER JOIN` combined with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) AS rn
    FROM #t1
), t2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) AS rn
    FROM #t2
)
SELECT COALESCE(t1.a, t2.a) AS a,  t1.b,    t2.b
FROM t1
FULL JOIN t2
  ON t1.a = t2.a
 AND t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/YPL92647)**